# use Mod_rewrite or trailslashes on uri

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite, uri

i would like to know what is the best option, im re-coding my own simple php framework, i used to have url lik this **index.php?mod=gallery&id=1** then i implement mod_rewrite and this look like this **gallery/1** but then i found out looking on MVC that you could use trailing slashes on the uri and forgot about GET params and treating url like this **index.php/gallery/1**.

But, i want to know which one is better to use. GET + Mod rewrite, or trailin slashes.
by the way using slashes on the uri i couldnt figure out how to use GET at the same time.

well let me know you experiences or advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using trailing slashes is more portable - your application can easily run on other web server software, like Microsoft IIS, lighttpd, nginx.

On the other side, using mod_rewrite or equivalent makes your URLs prettier and shorter, and to use parameters from trailing slashes version like `GET` array, you have to implement your own `REQUEST_URI` parser.

Comment: yeah, that it's what i was thinking but this mean that using trailing slashes is the most efficient way isn't?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this format:

```
index.php/gallery/1
```

you won't use `$_GET` but you will analyze the requested uri, extracted from the `$_SERVER` array in the `index.php` file. It doesn't need rewrite configuration, but IMO it looks ugly. I'd go for the clean rewritten version.